# Architecture of a product search engine

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, aws-lambda

I have developed a product search engine using AWS API Gateway, Lambda, ElasticSerach services. When user queries for a product, web server forward those request to API GW, then Lambda function is called and Lambda runs a search query in ES and sends back the results.

This works fine but I want query results to be cached somewhere if it returns more than 40 items so users can move to next page and so on without triggering the Lambda again and agin.

Is there an easy way of doing this without creating a web service using Node.js or something like that, I was checking ElastiCache but I couldn't find a proper use case.

Any idea how this can be achieved without maintaining a 24/7 web service?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want the lambda to retrieve 50 results from the DB, put all of them "somewhere" and give the user back only 10 so the user can ask for the rest from "somewhere" as opposed to calling the Lambda again?

Comment: I'm more interested in reducing number of ElasticSearch queries. I was thinking putting the results on memcached and send a unique key along with the first result set. Any subsequence request for the same search team can be served using the memcached for example next 10 result set of sort by price.

Comment: Why don't you introduce pagination with your API? GET /products?page=1 and only return first x results from elasticsearch. With this approach you can also enable caching on API Gateway so all your users get the same results hence less ElasticSearch requests.